# Images not showing up in a list when loading the data through argument parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, argparse

i am trying to load a set of images from a directory through argument parser in python3 which looks like this:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The path parameter for argument parser has been set in Intellij as following:

```
-i ~/Downloads/Person-Detection-in-Various-Postures-master/test_image
```

Now when i try to execute the following statement from my code i get an empty list instead of all the images populated in this list which i can later use in my code further.

```
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["images"]))
```

How can I populate this list to have all the images stored in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command line:

```
$ python yourpyfilename.py -i directoryname
```

Then you need to specify

```
imagePaths=os.lisdir(args["images"])
print(imagePaths)
```

It will give you list of images.
I hope it will work.